# How to send telethon message with non telegram event triggers

Tags: telegram, telethon

I'm trying to send a telegram message using telethon when I get a trigger from a button.

My telethon methods work fine when triggered by events like the NewMessage event, but how do I send a message (`client.send_message(user, msg)`) with other triggers (i.e. button is pressed, telethon sends a message)?

Currently all I'm getting are these errors:

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'send_to' was never awaited
```

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
    with client:
        client.start()
        while True:
            if (button):
                await client.send_message(int(chat),msg)
        client.run_until_disconnected()
```

*edit:*

In hindsight, my actual original question was oversimplified. I wasn't using a button, but voice commands, either way, a non-telegram trigger. With the help of the Telegram chat group @TelethonChat the answer was to use:

```py
    import asyncio

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    async def send_to(chat, msg):
        await client.send_message(chat, msg)
    
    def mainfunc():
        if (trigger):
            loop.create_task(send_to(chat, msg))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use events to do that. the event for clicking on a button is `events.CallbackQuery` [link is here](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telethon.events.html#module-telethon.events.callbackquery)

An example code would be as follow :

```py
from telethon import events
from telethon.tl.custom import Button

@client.on(events.CallbackQuery)
async def handler(event):
    await event.answer('You clicked {}!'.format(event.data))

client.send_message(chat, 'Pick one', buttons=[
    [Button.inline('Left'), Button.inline('Right')]]
])
```

you can find more examples here: https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/examples/telegram-client.html